# Tornado subroutines handling POST

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

I want to call a HTTP handler and from there start a process. This process is a while loop that calls a specific method and needs to run asynchronously every 5 minutes or so.

```
import logging
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
from tornado.locks import Event
from absl import app
import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger("proxy")

def call_external_api():
    logger.info("external API %s", datetime.datetime.now())
    raise ValueError('Failure')
    
class ScheduleObject:
    _instance = None
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
    
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_running'):
          logger.info("__init__")
          self._running = False
          self._event = Event()

    def start(self):
        if not self._running:
            logger.info("App process start...")
            self._running = True
            self._event.clear()
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(self._run_loopback)

    def stop(self):
        if self._running:
            logger.info("App process stop...")
            self._running = False
            self._event.set()

    async def _run_loopback(self):
        logger.info("**** App process _run_loopback")
        while self._running:
            logger.info("App process _running...")
            logger.info("Loopback process running...")
            try:
              call_external_api()
            except ValueError:
              logger.info("Exception handled...")
            # await self._event.wait(timeout=1)  # Wait for 1 second or until stop is called
            await tornado.gen.sleep(120)  # Allow other tasks to run

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, schedule):
        self._schedule = schedule

    def get(self):
        self._schedule.start()
        self.set_status(200)
        self.write("Loopback process started.")

    def on_finish(self):
        logger.info("Request completed")
    

def make_app():
    schedule = ScheduleObject()
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler, dict(schedule=schedule)),
    ])

def main(_):
    logger.info("App process running...")
    applicacion = make_app()
    applicacion.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(main)
```

I have the above code, but every time I call:

http://127.0.0.1:8888 I see the following:

```
I0614 05:28:03.333163 139917099460416 test.py:54] App process running...
I0614 05:28:03.333292 139917099460416 test.py:12] __init__
I0614 05:28:06.510964 139917099460416 test.py:18] App process start...
I0614 05:28:06.511689 139917099460416 web.py:2344] 200 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
I0614 05:28:06.511906 139917099460416 test.py:25] App process stop...
```

I needed to comment:

```
# await self._event.wait(timeout=1)  # Wait for 1 second or until stop is called
and remove `self._schedule.stop()` from on_finish
```

Question:

1. Is the above code the right pattern?
2. Am I missing something, I'm hardcoding 200OK, how can I return a better response in case I detect a failure?

Starting with Tornado, I tried Future, but decided to change to Events.
So far now code executes correctly/